# Generate Text (.txt) file for Data displayed in GSP

Tags: grails

I have a Grails app developed in 2.3.6

There's a GSP file with HTML and CSS elements in it, and that displays data in multiple tables with headers.

I want this data to be saved into a text file and save it. So basically what i want to do is, there will be a Export button in this GSP page, and when user clicks on it, it will download the text file with all the data from that GSP.

What i tried so far?

```
def textFile = {
    response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'Attachment;Filename="textFile.txt"')

    render view: 'textFile', contentType: 'text/plain'
}
```

The problem with above is, it saves not just data, but also HTML & CSS elements.

I don't want any HTML or CSS in the text file. Only data from GSP is needed.

Is there a simple way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is simple - you need another view withouth the html and css parts.

The rest of your code looks good. But Grails itself does not convert your view, it just sends the content type to the browser and the browser tries to diesplay the data according to the content type.

If you don't want to write a new view (in most cases, writing the new view is dead simple), you could write your own converter (something which strips the HTML and CSS from your file) by creating an afterView-Filter: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.0/guide/single.html#filters

Hope that helps